# How to update one specific field in view without render all view

Tags: angular, iframe, angular12

> i wrote a forum that contain 2 sections
>
> - post - father component
> - comments - child component inside post component
>
> post contain youtube iframe
>
> when i click on every place in comments child component, angular render
> the view and the youtube iframe jumping, if the video was playing
> its stopped, i solved this with

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

> now i have the same problem if i press on click event in post or
> comments components how i solve this problem?
>
> example not as forum but with iframe that show the problem
> https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-forked-xz5ro

Answer (score 0):

> the complete solution is to seprate every thing you can to different
> component as much as you can ,
> not child component, make it brother component

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

  ngOnChanges() {   
    if (this.postObj) {
       this.post =  Object.assign({}, this.postObj); 
    }
```